# SQL Select one column only with distinct on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

From this list:

```
Id  Material
5   100% Alpaca
8   100% Alpaca
32  100% Alpaca
113 100% Alpaca
271 100% Alpaca
437 100% Alpaca
114 100% Alpaca (Baby Royal)
115 100% Alpaca (Baby Royal)
116 100% Alpaca (Baby Royal)
250 100% Alpaca (Baby)
395 100% Alpaca (Royal)
176 100% Alpaca (Super Fine)
231 100% Alpine Stone Sheep
329 100% Alpine Stone Sheep
330 100% Alpine Stone Sheep
380 100% Aluminum
192 100% Angora
193 100% Angora
194 100% Angora
```

I would like only the 1st Id (to use for a cursor) on a distinct Material
Result expected:

```
Id
5   
114 
250 
395 
176 
231 
380 
192
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: *"to use for a cursor"* I would suggest a follow question would be "Why do you *want* to a Cursor?" SQL is a set based language; a `CURSOR` will be the slowest solution you can implement in the language. There are *very* few times you should really be using a `CURSOR`.

Comment: @Larnu, maybe because I'm a beginner and a cursor is for now the only possibility I know to have some "individual actions" on list. But if you have any suggestion... please!

Comment: I can't, I don't know what your goal is.

Comment: @Larnu, to exec a stored procedure for each Id

Comment: Why not have the Stored Procedure support multiple ID's?

Comment: @Larnu, I'll try this. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229659/discussion-between-philippe-and-larnu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min()`?

```
select min(id)
from t
group by material;
```